# Regex blocking special characters

Tags: php, regex, special-characters

I'm using PHP Version 5.3.27

I'm trying to get my regex to match whitespace, and special characters such as ♦◘•♠♥☻, the other known special characters which are %$#&*@ are already matched, but somehow the ones I mentioned before are not matched..

Current regex

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]+$/', $login)
```

My apology for asking two questions on the same subject. I hope this one is clear enough for you.

Comment: Please don't suggest me something like preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9-♦-[:space:]]+$/', $login) cause it's not like I will add every special character manually, there are tons of such characters ctrl + numbers can generate..

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't contain any reference to the special characters mentioned. You would need to include them in the character class for them to be matched.

To match those kinds of special characters you can use the **unicode** values.

**Example:**

```
\u0000-\uFFFF
\x00-\xFF
```

The top is UTF-16, the bottom is UTF-8.

Refer to a UTF-8/16 character table online to match up your symbols with their unicode values, then create a range to keep your expression short.

Comment: I know but there is another way for it. there are heaps of special characters generated as you do ctrl + some number, it's not like I will look for each of them to include manually. I had a regex that had this problem solved but I just lost it..

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
[\W]+
```

will match any non-word character.

Comment: Like this? preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]+$/[\W]+', $login){ doesn't solve the problem still..

Comment: may be you can use like this echo preg_match("/\w+/",$login);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\p{S}` character class (or `\p{So}`) that matches symbol characters *(that includes this kind of characters: ╭₠☪♛♣♞♉♆☯♫)*:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\h\p{S}]+$/u', $login)
```

To find more possibilities you can check the pcre documentation at: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

If you need to be more precise, the best way is to use character ranges in the character class. You can find code of characters [here](http://unicode-table.com/en).

Comment: neither does this work.. btw it should be (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\h\p{S}]+$/u', $login)) and not as what you posted.. thanks anyway I think im giving up on this

Comment: @user2986690: The problem is that your definition of special characters is too broad. I suggest you to update your question with your test string and to be more specific about what are the special characters you want.

Comment: I think my question is pretty much specific and direct to the point. I want preg_match to confirm only English letters and numbers, no special characters such as ╛◘.♥☻☺ because I enter them and they get confirmed as valid.

Comment: I've seen a question on this website about 2 days ago and it had my problem solved, there was someone who posted a good working preg match code, i just got like half of my data wipped off and it happened to be included with them..